# Trouble Extracting Numeric Values for Summation in a Yii Grid Column Using TSumColumn

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm facing an issue while attempting to compute the sum of data within a column named "hours" using the **TSumColumn::class** in Yii. The problem arises due to additional content within the cells, specifically encapsulated within `<small>(' . Utility::computeDays($model->hours) . 'gg)</small>.`

I aim to extract only the `Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->hours)` part from each cell to compute the sum at the bottom of the column. However, it's crucial to retain the `<small>(' . Utility::computeDays($model->hours) . 'gg)</small>` part for display purposes in each cell.

Here's the current column definition:

```
[
                    'attribute' => 'hours',
                    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                        return '<span class="font-montserrat bold text-success fs-16">' 
                        . Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->hours) // only sum this value
                        . '</span> <small>(' . Utility::computeDays($model->hours) . 'gg)</small>'; //don't include this value while summing but keep it displayed in the cell
                    },
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'class' => TSumColumn::class,
                ],
```

Here is the **TsumColumn** class I'm using:

```
use kartik\grid\DataColumn;

class TSumColumn extends DataColumn
{
    public function getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index)
    {
        $value = parent::getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index);
        if (is_numeric(str_replace(',','.',strip_tags($value)))) {
            $this->footer += round(str_replace(',','.',strip_tags($value)),2);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the footer cell content.
     * The default implementation simply renders [[footer]].
     * This method may be overridden to customize the rendering of the footer cell.
     * @return string the rendering result
     * @throws \yii\base\InvalidConfigException
     */
    protected function renderFooterCellContent()
    {
        if($this->footer !== null && trim($this->footer) !== '') {
           if($this->format == 'currency') {
               return \Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($this->footer);
           }
           return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($this->footer);
        }

        return $this->grid->emptyCell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you are formatting value for output in `value` callback instead of `format` callback. Because of that you have to parse already formatted html code to get value for footer.

If you defined your column like this:

```php
[
     'attribute' => 'hours',
     'format' => function ($value, $formatter) {
         return '<span class="font-montserrat bold text-success fs-16">' 
             . $formatter->asDecimal($value) . '</span> <small>(' 
             . Utility::computeDays($value) . 'gg)</small>';
         },
     'class' => TSumColumn::class,
]
```

Then you wouldn't need to parse html code in your `TSumColumn` class because `parent::getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index);` would return the value of `$model->hours` property. So your `TSumColumn::getDataCellValue` would simply look like this:

```php
class TSumColumn extends DataColumn
{
    public function getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index)
    {
        $value = parent::getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index);
        $this->footer += round($value, 2);
        return $value;
    }
    // ... other methods ...
}
```

Ultimately, if the purpose of `TSumColumn` class is just to sum values you can get rid of it completely and sum values using `array_sum` and `ArrayHelper::getColumn()`:

```php
[
    'attribute' => 'hours',
    'format' => function ($value, $formatter) {
        return '<span class="font-montserrat bold text-success fs-16">' 
            . $formatter->asDecimal($value) . '</span> <small>(' 
            . Utility::computeDays($value) . 'gg)</small>';
        },
    'footer' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal(array_sum(
        \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(
            $dataProvider->getModels(),
            fn ($model) => round($model->hours, 2),
        )
    )),
]
```

Assuming `$dataProvider` is a variable where you have the instance of your data provider. The `$dataProvider->getModels()` will return array of all models on current page. I've used callback as second parameter in `ArrayHelper::getColumn()` method call to apply rounding to values of `hours` property.

Comment: I think this is a better approach, :( event if the person THINKS that he created a nice bicycle. That's how we should do this. Your approach is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve that by extending a new class from **TsumColumn** and use it in my gridView table.

```
class SumColumnOneValue extends TSumColumn
{
    public function getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index)
    {
        $value = parent::getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index);
        $numericValue = 0;

        // Look for content within <span> tags and extract numeric values for summation
        preg_match('/<span[^>]*>([\d.,]+)<\/span>/', $value, $matches);
        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $numericValue = str_replace(',', '.', $matches[1]);
            $this->footer += round($numericValue, 2);
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Multi Inheritance in yii2 and overall in simple cases is not a best solutions for the modern frameworks. except you are not dealing with symfony.